# Laravel preventing user from accessing other users resource **url

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am passing a specific resource in the url, for ex.
https://www.example.com/{companyID}

And in the controller I can access the resource by

```
public function index($companyID)
{
    // Code Here
}
```

I need to block users from changing the url and accessing other companyIDs from the system. Currently its open and is a security risk. I checked out Laravel Gate and Policy's but fail to see how this could be implemented for my case.

What I am really looking for is something in the AuthServiceProvider boot method that can check if the user really is the owner of the resource before continuing with the code.

Any help?

Comment: Use a middleware to only allow the user access to their company ID

Comment: How is the logged in user related to a company? If you edit your question with the database structure I can formulate you an answer on how to do that :-)

Comment: If you could paste your Company Model it'd help massively and I too will be able to provide an answer for you.

Comment: do you know how to get the current user details in controller or have you already enable Authentication?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned before, you can do that by creating a Middleware that checks if your resource should be available to the logged in user.

See some details about middleware [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware)

First, create a Middleware via `php artisan`, like this

```
php artisan make:middleware AuthResource
```

Next, add it to your `App\Http\Kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'AuthResource' => \App\Http\Middleware\AuthResource::class,
];
```

In your routes, you can now do the following:

```
Route::get('{companyID}', ['uses' => CompanyController@index, 'middleware' => 'AuthResource']);
```

That way, your `AuthResource` middleware is used whenenver the route is called.
In your `App\Http\Middleware\AuthResource.php` you have to change the code from

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    return $next($request);
}
```

to something that checks if the resource is available to the currently logged in user. 
I assume that your companies table has a field `user_id`, which links the Company to a User. If your data structure is different, you need to change the code accordingly.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ($request->route('companyID')) {
        $company = Company::find($request->route('companyID'));
        if ($company && $company->user_id != auth()->user()->id) {
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

That way we check if the a route parameter with the name `companyID` exists, and if it does we check if it is available to the currently logged in user. If no `companyID` parameter is available, the page can be loaded without any restrictions.

That way you can copy/paste the code within the middleware for any parameters so that the middleware does work for multiple resources (not only companies).

Comment: Given yours is more detailed than mine i have removed mine :) - Bear in mind we can only assume that `Company` is the model name and the same for the fillable of `user_id`

Answer (score 1):

This is can be done easily by middleware. But I’ll do this in more understandable way.
I assume that your user has one to one relationship with company.
So first create the relationship,
In your User model,

```
Public function company() {
    return $this->hasOne(‘App\Company’);
}
```

Company model

```
Public function user(){
   return $this->belongsTo(‘App\User’);
}
```

So, now make Authenticate by running php artisan make:auth . more details on [Authenticate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication)

And now in your controller,

```
public function index($companyID)
{
    $current_user = Auth::user();
    $user_company = $current_user->company; // get the current user's company details
    If($companyID == $user_company->id){
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this would require this code to be present on all functions, which can be cumbersome further down the road. Matthias S solution allows for one code to rule all.