# How to use signed route as blade view in controller function

Tags: laravel, routes, signed

I have a team-based app where each team can only see and function with their own views and data. There is profile view where teams can change info about their team settings with a URL like '.../admin/teams/2/show_profile' The number 2 represents the team's ID number so if a user chooses to do so they could change the number to any other number and the view would pull up the profile details of the other team. So I need to make it so uses can not change this specific URL to keep them from being able to override the route. I have been looking at using a signed URL as the way to should be done but I have been having trouble implementing it in the controller. I have already added`use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;`to the top of the controller.

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('teams/{id}/show_profile', ['uses' => 'Admin\TeamsController@show_profile', 'as' => 'teams.show_profile'])->middleware('signed');
```

Here is my Controller function:

```
public function show_profile($id)
    {
        if (! Gate::allows('team_view')) {
            return abort(401, 'Sorry you are not authorized for this action at this time');
        }

        $created_bies = \App\User::get()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('global.app_please_select'), '');
        $created_by_teams = \App\Team::get()->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend(trans('global.app_please_select'), '');

        $query = \App\User::query();
        $query->select('users.*')
            ->leftJoin('team_user', function ($join) use ($id) { // include users with this church as an additional church
                $join->on('team_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id');
                $join->on('team_user.team_id', '=', DB::raw("'".$id."'"));
            })
            ->where('users.team_id', $id)
            ->orWhere('team_user.team_id', '=', $id);
        $query = $query->getQuery();
        $user_list = $query->get();
        $user_id_array = [];
        foreach ($user_list as $one_user) {
            $user_id_array[] = $one_user->id;
        }
        $users = \App\User::whereIn('id', $user_id_array)->get();

        $interests = \App\Interest::where('created_by_team_id', $id)->get();
        $activity = \App\Activity::where('created_by_team_id', $id)->get();
        $usersettings = \App\Usersetting::where('created_by_team_id', $id)->get();

        $team = Team::findOrFail($id);

        return view('admin.teams.show_profile', compact('team', 'users', 'interests', 'activity', 'usersettings'));
    }
```

So the question I can't figure out is what do I need to do next generate the signed URL I have tried modifying the return view with some version of `return URL::signedRoute(...);` or `$url = action('TeamController@team_profile', [...]);` with parameters passed through the in parentheses and brackets, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to function properly.  I know the middleware on the route is functioning because I have tested it using the original return view. So the question is what do I need to do to transition a return view to a signed route URL?

Comment: I would code a middleware to Check if the user's team id is the same of the URL,if not, give 403 error and handle it. Assuming That you have a table with users team id.

Comment: @hmmeves. It sounds like an intriguing alternative but I don't know anything about that. Might you have a suggestion on what the code would look like or any links i could study to try and accomplish this?

Comment: @ hmmeves are you thinking something like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49689329/laravel-preventing-user-from-accessing-other-users-resource-url)

Comment: Yes, Like That.

Answer (score 1):

in blade use Signed URL as below::

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::signedRoute
```

as an example

```
<a href="{{  \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::signedRoute('formreportlog.showformlog',['report_id'=>$person->id   ] )   }}"
                                        class="btn btn-success">@lang('user.active')</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add the new ValidateSignature to your route middleware in /app/Http/Kernel.php.

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
       // ...
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
+   'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
   ];
 }
```

Currently, we have the following event.rsvp route in our routes/web.php file.

```
 Route::get('event/{id}/rsvp/{user}/{response}', function ($id, $user, $response) 
 {
   // Add response from user for event.
 })->name('event.rsvp')->middleware('signed');
```

and our URL is generated like so

```
use \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL;
Url::signedRoute('event.rsvp', ['id' => 25, 'user' => 100, 'response' => 'yes']);
```

which generates:

```
https://example.com/event/25/rsvp/100/yes?signature=30a3877b00890fff0d7ca25f82c6387ff16a98d21008ddc9689ed3c20ef13cd4
```

Comment: So based on that, my question is, how does one convert the information from a functioning return view route like my example into a functioning URL::singedRoute? This is my problem I can't get the URL::signedRoute to generate a proper blade view in my app. Any suggestions?